# How to get value from multiple collection at a time from cloud firastore of firebase with react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5kJw.png)

my firebase firestore setup is like this, and i want to get all the data of collection like family, friend, other at same time in same page and show it as flatlist.

please help to get solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, based on your Firestore structure, the following code should help you fetching all `documents` from a certain `subcollection`:

```
 return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc('1')
   .collection('family').get()
   .then((querySnapshot) => {
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
     });
   });
 };
```

The subcollection "family" was used in the above example. Note that for this to work, the collection name *should* be predictable. Firebase does not allow to retrieve a list of collections with mobile/web client libraries at the moment, as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

*Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.*

Now, if you are interested in querying across multiple subcollections, you may want to use [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). For example, you can query all `users` who have a `friend` named `John`.

```
var users = db.collectionGroup('friend').where('friendName', '==', 'John');
users.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
});
```

Note that `user` and `friend` are both collections, and `John` would reference a document within the friend's subcollection.

To find specific React Native for Firebase examples, this is the officially recommended [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#querysnapshot).

Comment: Thank's sllopis, it helps me lot..